# how to update to a specific commit in git?

Tags: git

I am new to git and I would like to know if I can update my local repository to a specific commit. 
Is this possible using checkout?

```
git checkout <commitId>
```

exp

```
git checkout 55215860452c5c6fb11eac6f51d63abb187e7
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that's what `git checkout` does. You can leave out the end of the commit hash if the part you provide is unambiguous.

Comment: If that sha is not the referent of a branch, this will put you in a detached state.  That's not a big deal, but you might prefer `git checkout -b new-branch-name $SHA`

Comment: It's fairly rare (for certain definitions of rare) to checkout via a hash.  Usually, your are more interested in some ref (which is equivalent, but has a human friendly name, like a branch name).  And, if you are interested in a particular hash that is not labeled with a ref, now is the time to create that ref (since you are interested in it.)  Creating a branch that refers to this commit is (often) what you want to do, and `git checkout -b` does that for you.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit because it changes the question completely, invalidating existing answers. You should ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use `git checkout <sha1>`.

As stated in the comments, you can use:

- The full SHA1 hash of the commit
- Any prefix of the SHA1 that isn't ambiguous
- Any ref that also points to this specific commit

Comment: No, you don't have to use the SHA1 hash.  You can use the SHA1 hash, or any prefix of the SHA1 that isn't ambiguous, or any ref that also points to the commit.  You *can* use the SHA1 which more or less answers the question - for which reason I won't downvote - but as written this answer is very misleading to anyone who doesn't know how to use `git checkout`

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Thank you for correcting this. I've updated my answer accordingly to be more precise.

Comment: After a git checkout <sha1> I am in a detached state. Why I am not on the same branch as the commit? I want to use the checkout commit for an update. So, the client can checkout the feature selected (where the feature is the commit). He may see more features and he choose which one to use. Is that possible using git checkout?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by "update my local repository". If you want to remain on your current branch, you can reset your branch to a prior commit with:

```
git reset --hard <SHA1>
```

This will put the state of your branch to that of SHA1. The command git checkout changes the branch you are working on, so it will also change the state of the local repository, but the branch will no longer be the same.

Comment: @ JSeven: I want something like `git pull` with condition not to merge with the last commit, but with a prior one.

Comment: I think `git reset --soft <sha1>` will help me

Comment: Keep in mind that --soft will leave anything that's not on that SHA1 as modified on the repository. That is, the files won't reflect exaclty what the SHA1 has, unless you do a git clean or a git reset --hard.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it keeps with the current branch, as opposed to a `git checkout` which results into a 'detached HEAD' state.

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the way with full steps to go to a specific commit in Git.**

```
1. git clone https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters
2. cd bitters
3. git checkout 95cd30a  

#  You can find your commit number in git logs or in website.

4. git log
```

Answer (score -1):

git commit --amend -m "New commit message."
But only for the previous commit and the commit has not been pushed to a remote repository.

Comment: this solution is for added  new changes to your current commit, but not for updating a local git to a specific remote commit